# Scala Map[String, MutableList]()

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

I want to create mutable Map which contains string as key and MutableList as value.

```
val myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, MutableList]()
```

like this:

```
mymap = Map("a" -> MutableList(1, 2, 3), "b" -> MutableList(5, 6, 7))
```

but whne i try to create it raises error:

```
scala> var myval = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, scala.collection.mutable.MutableList]()
<console>:10: error: class MutableList takes type parameters
   var myval = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, scala.collection.mutable.MutableList]()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MutableList[A]` expects a type paremeter. You should use a `var` for mutable state and not `val` as well:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutableMap, MutableList}

var myMap = MutableMap[String, MutableList[Int]]()
myMap = MutableMap("a" -> MutableList(1, 2, 3), "b" -> MutableList(5, 6, 7))
```

Comment: yeah, usually the REPL is your friend ;)

Comment: can you explain REPL??

Comment: It's the Scala interpreter (usually called REPL for Read-Evaluate-Print Loop). If you have `scala` in your path, just open a new terminal, type `scala` and have fun. See http://www.scala-lang.org/download/install.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't share @jarandaf's point of view about `var` and mutable state:

> You should use a var for mutable state and not val as well

For me using `var` is orthogonal to using a mutable data structure.
There is no problem at all using it like this:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutableMap, MutableList}
scala> val myMap = MutableMap("a" -> MutableList(1, 2, 3), "b" -> MutableList(5, 6, 7))
```

And you can still change the values of the map (**never** use a mutable value as the key unless you want to have some fun debugging) using mutation like this:

```
scala> myMap.get("a").map(_ += 42)
scala> myMap
res1: MutableMap[String,MutableList[Int]] = Map("b" -> MutableList(5, 6, 7), "a" -> MutableList(1, 2, 3, 42))
```

Actually if I use a `var` I normally use an *immutable* data structure because for me there is seldom a reason to use both a `var` **and** a mutable data structure.

```
scala> var myMap2 = Map("a" -> List(1,2,3))
scala> myMap2 = myMap2.updated("a",myMap2("a") :+ 42)
myMap2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(a -> List(1, 2, 3, 42))
```